# Display float value on the GUI with text - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code that I wrote, trying to display the timetakene variable on the gui through text. The debug log spits out the correct time and timetakene variable is working, but it is not updating the text script.

Im fetching this variable from another Scene in my unity game. Would that cause some problems?

Thank you.

UPDATE
I changed the font size down and it displayed correctly... I think the text box was too small. Kicking myself right now

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class MatchTimeDisplay : MonoBehaviour {
public float TimeTakene;
public GameObject TimeDisplay01;

    void Update () {
        TimeTakene = MatchTimer.matchtimetaken;
        Debug.Log(TimeTakene);
        TimeDisplay01.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Match Time: " + TimeTakene;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned a gameobject with a text-component to the TimeDisplay01 field in the unity inspector?

Comment: Yep, i have assigned one

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is assign the Text component to a variable and use that in the Update method.  You really should avoid calling GetComponent like that in Update when there is no need.

See if in doing so does it resolve your problem